# PYQT5 find the colour of a pixel

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

The following code randomly plots pixels on a label I want to know if the pixel has already been plotted by checking the colour of the pixel prior to plotting it.

```
import sys
import random
from time import sleep
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from test import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer

size = 500

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
    # make QTimer
        self.qTimer = QTimer()
        self.qTimer.setInterval(1)
        self.qTimer.timeout.connect(self.updateGUI)
        self.qTimer.start()

        canvas = QPixmap(size, size)
        canvas.fill(Qt.white)
        self.label.setPixmap(canvas)

    def updateGUI(self):
        painter = QPainter(self.label.pixmap())
        x = random.randint(0, size-1)
        y = random.randint(0, size-1)
        painter.drawPoint(x, y)       
        painter.end()
        self.update()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()      
window.show()
app.exec()
```

I came across the following code but it does not work in my case.
There is no error thrown but the color number printed does not change as expected

```
    pixmap = self.label.grab()
    img = pixmap.toImage()
    color = img.pixelColor(x, y)
    print('one',color)
```

Comment: If you just want to know if a pixel has already been painted, there's little point in checking its color: just keep an internal list (or a set) that contains the coordinates you draw. Besides, you should not use `grab()`, as it captures the *whole* widget, and if the pixmap does not cover the whole size you will get inconsistent results: just get the current pixmap.

Comment: Thanks, musicamante in this instance there are many thousand-pixel possibilities (500*500) I was hoping that there was a simple way of just reading the pixel value that I had missed. You are correct about the grab() if I read the value several times without setting a pixel I get a different reading each time.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation this is the soution that works for me.

```
    x = random.randint(0, self.size-1)
    y = random.randint(0, self.size-1)

    pixmap = self.label.pixmap()
    self.img = pixmap.toImage()
    col = self.img.pixel(x,y)
    col_rgb = QColor(col).getRgb()

    if col_rgb == (255, 255, 255, 255):  #White
        painter.drawPoint(x, y)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).